# Apachi POI - how to get cell content and change sheet in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

In Selenium Apachi POI - how can I get cell content and change sheet?

Scenario #

1. I have first sheet as "Test" which has 2 Test Scenario in 2 column as

   TestScn      ---------------- RunMod

   Login---------------------           NO

   Checkemail -------------Yes
2. Now I have 2 more sheets named after "TestScn" (Login & Checkemail)
3. Can please provide Webdriver code to navigate to the sheet if RunMod is "Yes" & extract data from that sheet & come back to the first ("Test") sheet

Comment: Selenium and POI are entirely different, please don't mix. All you need is just an example on how to change/move from one sheet to another.

Comment: @Onu: Did you got what you want??

Comment: @Sankumarsingh, Sorry I was taken by other stuff, but you code worked & was a lifesaver. Thanks a Lot

Comment: @Onu: Put `testRowItr.next();` just before while loop.

Answer (score 0):

`setActiveSheet(...)` - Seems to be your solution according to the [docs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html)

Another easy solution :

```
//Get first sheet from the workbook
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the piece of code.

```
int RunModeIndex = 1;
int SheetIndex = 0;
Iterator <Row> testRowItr=wb.getSheet("test").iterator();
while(testRowItr.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(testRowItr.next().getCell(RunModeIndex).toString());
    if(testRowItr.next().getCell(RunModeIndex).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
        Sheet sheetToExecute = wb.getSheet(testRowItr.next().getCell(SheetIndex).toString());
        //now sheetToExecute have RunMode = Yes. It is the sheet on which you have to perform execution
        }else{
            //code for the sheet having runMode  = No
    }
}
```